# How can I perform a worker when a date of my table is equal to current date - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

How can I perform a worker when a date of my table is equal to current date on Ruby on Rails 7.0, I'm using Sidekiq and Sidekiq Schedule and I have this table

```rb
class CreateDraws < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :draws do |t|

      t.string :name
      t.integer :porcentual
      t.datetime :datefrom
      t.datetime :dateto
      t.string :firstAward
      t.string :secondAward
      t.integer :first_winner, default: nil
      t.integer :second_winner, default: nil
      t.integer :n_ticket
      t.integer :limit
      t.integer :number_solds, default: 0
      t.boolean :has_winners, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want to perform a worker always when dateto is equal than current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dateto` is static data.  You need an action or event to trigger your worker's job.

For example:

1. After the record is created, queue a job
2. On an hourly schedule, query the database filtering records on `dateto` being the current date

Within the job, you can perform behavior with your records, even if that behavior is to do nothing.